# Viewing SCHEMA logs for postgresql in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql, pg

I'm having a hard time trying to get logging to include postgres schema changes in it.

I've isolated the line of code that blocks them, but rather than being a configurable option, it seems to be hard coded that they don't appear. Right now I'm chaining the method that sets the `schema_search_path` to log then, but the sql is already being executed through the normal method which is logged so it'd be nice to take advantage of that. Here's the offending line of code:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/activerecord/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb#L27

How would I go about subscribing to those logs too?

Comment: I take it you're referring to Rails-side logging? PostgreSQL's own logs will include schema changes if `log_statement` is set to `ddl` or higher.

Comment: Yes that's right, this is Rails logging in test.log.